# Can't write to other users "you have write permission turned off"

Tags: linux, centos, bash, write

For some reason I'm not able to write to other users on my system.

```
[root@hostname ~]# write
write: you have write permission turned off.
[root@hostname ~]# mesg y
[root@hostname ~]# mesg
is y
[root@hostname ~]# write
write: you have write permission turned off.
```

What else needs to be enabled/corrected for this to work?

Comment: Open a second session, and using `w` to get the tty of your first user, use `write user yourtty` and see what that does.

Comment: This gives the same result.

Comment: Check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for SELinux denials.

Comment: @MichaelHampton There's a whole lot going on in here, but I don't see anything that looks like an error.

Comment: What is the result of the command  "ls -l /dev/tty"

Answer (score 1):

Testing `strace write` and `strace mesg` reveals a slight difference in how they identify your tty.

`write` will first do `readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", ...)` to find the name of the `tty` and then do a `stat` call on the resulting path.

`mesg` on the other hand will call `fstat(1, ...)` which skips the step of using `readlink` and doesn't rely on the `/proc` file system.

Notice that they also look at different file descriptors `0` vs `1`. Normally an interactive shell will have file descriptors  `0`, `1`, and `2` all referencing the same tty. If you have somehow gotten your shell running with `0` and `1` referencing something different for example if you had redirected one of them, that could explain the discrepancy between the output from `mesg` and `write`.

If the file descriptors are both referencing the same tty, another possible reason for the discrepancy could be that your `/proc` mount is not behaving as expected or the character device inode for your tty has been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

When running as root with `mesg` disabled (returning `n`), I get the same error you have.  Running the command `mesg y` enables me to run write.  Running as `root` I can write to users that have `mesg` disabled, which I can't do as non-root.

There are multiple utilities that provide the `write` functionality.  All of them will need to be able to write to terminals.  However, as you are running as `root` permissions should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit `/etc/login.defs` and change `TTYPERM 0600` to `TTYPERM 0620`.